# UIButton with shaded background color?

Tags: ios, uibutton

I want to create a button looking like the Delete Contact button of iPhones. My button would be blue if possible. Anyone knows how to do it simply ?

[image: http://www.libellules.ch/images/delete_contact_iphone4.png]

Thanks for your help

Comment: where do you want this button to appear?  in the table view cell or somewhere else in that above view?

Comment: Yes somewhere else, using a UIButton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to create a png for the background and use:

for a `UIBarButtonItem`

```
[self.myBarButtonItem setBackgroundImage: [UIImage imageNamed: myimage] forState: UICOntrolStateNormal barMetrics: UIBarMetricsDefault]
```

or for a `UIButton`

```
[self.myButton setBackgroundImage: [UIImage imageNamed: myimage] forState: UICOntrolStateNormal]
```